# Jquery themeroller icon as input text background

Tags: jquery-ui, css, jquery-ui-theme

How can I insert a themeroller icon inside a `<input type="text">`, as a `background-image`, at the left?

I don't have direct access to the images because the theme is dynamic. Don't know at runtime which theme is current. I can only depend on the class names like `ui-icon`, `ui-icon-email`, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct CSS solution, JQuery UI Icons are shown using background-position property to choose the correct "icon carpet" offset, so adding the background-size property provoques it to render no icon.

Maybe you can try a more complex solution, like INPUT and SPAN elements together with no borders between them and putting the background icon in the latest.

I wish I could be of more help, sorry.